# Web-Service Deployment Error

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0 for web-service deployment and eclipse IDE.I have made the web service using eclipse but when i close eclipse and try to use the web service it gives an error while giving the result stating

> exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

but when i start eclipse and start the tomcat localhost server(i.e clicking Run Tomcat Server at localhost) from eclipse then the web service works fine and give the result as it should.
How to use the web-service without starting eclipse and just starting tomcat 7.0 normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Package you application as a `war` (Web ARchive) file
2. Put it in your `<TOMCAT_DIR>/webapps` folder.
3. Start Tomcat using `<TOMCAT_DIR>/bin/startup.bat`

Comment: I have packaged the application into a WAR file and put it into the webapps folder but there is not startup.bat file in <TOMCAT_DIR>/bin/startup.bat.I tried starting from service manager but didn't work.It is giving the same error as before

Comment: no there is nothing,cannot find any errors inside it,looks fine
Is there any other way to do.

Comment: Thank you,i have solved it.The problem was not eclipse but was on the registry.It was not able to access the registry to start tomcat.I tried it in windows XP and it worked fine....
Thanks Again..